# Create new fields based on condition and append that output df to another df General dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create new fields from a df based on if the conditions match. Below is the df I am trying to use.

```
abc<- tibble::tribble(
  ~type,               ~match_type, ~count,
  "type b", "alpha",           2,
  "type a", "alpha",           4,
  "type b",           "alpha",           1,
  "type a",           "alpha",           2,
  "type a",    "beta",          32,
  "type a",    "beta",          40,
  "type a",    "beta",          39,
  "type a",    "beta",          40,
  "type a",    "beta",          55,
  "type b",    "beta",          66,
  "type b",    "beta",          35,
  "type b",    "beta",          72,
  "type b",    "beta",          54,
  "type b",    "beta",          30,
  "type b",    "beta",          22,
  "type b",    "beta",          24,
  "type b",    "beta",          13,
  "type b",    "beta",          32,
  "type b",    "beta",          18,
  "type b",    "beta",          40
)
```

Now if `match_type` is `alpha` then create a new field called alpha and sum up the count numbers there and similar for beta.

This is what I have tried so far and the error which I get.

```
abc %>%  mutate(alpha=(count[match_type =="alpha"]),
                beta=(count[match_type =="beta"]))

Error: `mutate()` argument `alpha` must be recyclable.
ℹ `alpha` is `(count[match_type == "alpha"])`.
x `alpha` can't be recycled to size 20.
ℹ `alpha` must be size 20 or 1, not 4.
```

I am trying to create a new df like this (the numbers might not add up in this example)

```
result <- tibble::tribble(
  ~type,               ~alpha, ~beta,
  "type b", 22,           2,
  "type a", 12,           4
)
```

Once I get this above df I want to insert those values in this dataframe based on the field `type` which as of now are `na`.

```
final_df <-tibble::tribble(
  ~type,               ~alpha, ~beta, val1 ,val2,
  "type b", na,           na, 4,5,
  "type a", na,           na,3,2,
  "type c", 22,           2,2,3,
  "type d", 12,           4,12,12,
  "type e", 22,           2,4,5,
  "type f", 12,           4,3,4
)
```

Am I doing too many steps. is there a simple way to do it.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the `sum` and wants to reshape, use `pivot_wider` and then do a `right_join` with the 'final_fd' and `coalesce` the 'alpha', 'beta' columns (assuming that `na` is `NA`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
abc %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = match_type, values_from = count, 
         values_fn = list(count = sum)) %>%
  right_join(final_df, by = 'type') %>%
  transmute(type, alpha = coalesce(alpha.y, alpha.x), 
       beta = coalesce(beta.y, beta.x), val1, val2)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#  type   alpha  beta  val1  val2
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 type b     3   406     4     5
#2 type a     6   206     3     2
#3 type c    22     2     2     3
#4 type d    12     4    12    12
#5 type e    22     2     4     5
#6 type f    12     4     3     4
```

---

Or using `data.table`, do a `join` after reshaping the 'abc' to 'wide' format with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(final_df)[dcast(setDT(abc), type ~ match_type, 
   value.var = 'count', sum), c('alpha','beta') := 
        .(i.alpha, i.beta), on = .(type)]
```

#### data

```
final_df <- structure(list(type = c("type b", "type a", "type c", "type d", 
"type e", "type f"), alpha = c(NA, NA, 22, 12, 22, 12), beta = c(NA, 
NA, 2, 4, 2, 4), val1 = c(4, 3, 2, 12, 4, 3), val2 = c(5, 2, 
3, 12, 5, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```